# Laravel: controller resource index does not return view or string

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

I have created a controller using:

```
php artisan make:controller VideoCategoryController --resource
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::resource('/admin/video/category', 'VideoCategoryController');
```

The `index()` doesn't return data, but other methods work properly.

```
public function index()
{ 
    return 'test'; 
}
```

Comment: Show us how you are accessing the route

Answer (score 0):

Is this solved? Are you trying to return it to the view?

```
public function index() { 
return view('test');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The function name should be:

`getIndex()` instead of `index()`.

Please refer:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers